# Boot Linux from USB Stick - does not work with all sticks - device descriptor error read 64 error -110 -71 enumerate - address

Tags: debian, usb-drive, boot-loader, bootable

this is driving me nuts: i have EXACTLY the same [image](http://linux-workshops.de/stick/ideal-linux-usb_stick_image_full_16GByte_2017-04.img.gz) written via dd to USB Stick:

SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 32GB SDCZ48-032G

```
it works with Model: BM171026162B 

     but with Model: BM160825364B
```

it gives me this error that leads nowhere?

"device descriptor error read 64 error -110 -71 unable to enumerate usb device - device not accepting address"

[image]

for details: http://linux-workshops.de/ideal-linux-stick/

am i assuming this is a "defect" or change in hardware of the stick that makes it unusable?

is the missing module: ehci-orion the problem?

does it need to be compiled into the kernel? (i guess)

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&searchon=contents&keywords=ehci-orion.ko

Comment: Can you do a binary comparison of full drive images? One of the sticks can be faulty. And the downvoter is a troll.

Comment: Thanks for your help - as you can see on this picture - i have 4 sticks (two of each model-version) and 2 sticks work 2 sticks fail: http://linux-workshops.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SanDisk-Ultra-USB-3.0-32GB-SDCZ48-032G-BM160825364B-not-working-as-linux-boot-stick4.jpg (Model: BM171026162B works, Model: BM160825364B comes with the error seen in the black and white screenshot)

Comment: this stick does not work:
`lsusb -v|grep San
 Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra
 idVendor           0x0781 SanDisk Corp.
 iManufacturer           1 SanDisk
 lsusb -v -d 0781:5581
2c2
< Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra ---
> Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra
16c16
< iSerial 3 4C530001220830110261 --- >   iSerial                 3 4C530001181014123401
84c84
< Device Status: 0x0000 --- > Device Status:     0x000c
85a86,87
>   U1 Enabled
>   U2 Enabled `

Comment: update: the version/model (fake SanDisk?)
`BM160825364B does not work.`

`BM171026162B works!`

`BM161125735B  works!`

`BM180126162B WORKS TOO!`